# How to load a csv file with uncommon structure in python to eventually pivot the data?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pivot, unpivot

I'm having problems to load a simple .csv file with `pd.read_csv()`.
The problem is the last header which groups multiple 'columns'.

The fifth columns looks like this:
**Data_Series**
0; 0,5; 1; 2; 4; 6
12; 15; 25; 33; 23
0; 0,3; 2; 3; 7; 8; 8,5; 9,5
22; 45; 35; 48; 55; 60; 62; 58

Expecting result should be a DataFrame with 5 columns
( with the Statistic column being pivoted [X, Y] to contain the Data_Series values ).

Any idea how to approach this? Thanks

Comment: How do you get the file? Normally if values are grouped in one column they would be enclosed by a defined character like ""

Comment: From an iot device. The file looks just like that but with thousands of values under Data_Series. It is not possible to change the original format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd

df_list = []

with open('data_in.csv', 'r') as f:
    headers = False
    for line in f:
        if not headers:
            headers = line.strip().split('; ')
            continue
        
        # Machine; Process; Date; Statistic; Data_Series -> 5 columnss -> split 4 times
        unparsed = line.strip().split('; ', len(headers)-1)
        
        # split the last column
        parsed = [float(val.replace(',', '.')) for val in unparsed[-1].split('; ')]
        
        # add data to list after removeing any spaces on "Statistic"
        df_list.append(unparsed[:-2] + [unparsed[-2].strip()] + [parsed])

df = pd.DataFrame(df_list, columns=headers)

# pivot > explode > reset_index
df_new = df.pivot(index=["Machine", "Process", "Date"], columns="Statistic", values="Data_Series").explode(list('XY')).reset_index()

# remove columns names
df_new.columns.name = None
```

| Machine | Process | Date | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | P22 | 08.12.2015 | 0 | 12 |
| A | P22 | 08.12.2015 | 0.5 | 15 |
| A | P22 | 08.12.2015 | 1 | 25 |
| A | P22 | 08.12.2015 | 2 | 33 |
| A | P22 | 08.12.2015 | 4 | 23 |
| A | P22 | 08.12.2015 | 6 | 45 |
| A | PX67 | 09.12.2015 | 0 | 22 |
| A | PX67 | 09.12.2015 | 0.3 | 45 |
| A | PX67 | 09.12.2015 | 2 | 35 |
| A | PX67 | 09.12.2015 | 3 | 48 |
| A | PX67 | 09.12.2015 | 7 | 55 |
| A | PX67 | 09.12.2015 | 8 | 60 |
| A | PX67 | 09.12.2015 | 8.5 | 62 |
| A | PX67 | 09.12.2015 | 9.5 | 58 |

Comment: Thanks for this approach. It works wonderfully well. This is the final solution. I just noticed one thing, if a series within one statistic has a different length when applying the explode(list('XY')) function we get an "columns must have matching element counts"; otherwise thanks again for this great code.

Comment: You're welcome, This error will always occur if they have an unmatched number of elements.

Comment: @Susy84 Sorry I didn't clarify that I added `; 45` at the end of line 2 in `data` file to match the one in the picture.

Answer (score 1):

Using `csv.reader` and pandas `pivot` + `explode`

```py
text = """Machine;Process;Date;Statistic;Data_Series
A;P22;08.12.2015;X;0;0,5;1;2;4;6
A;P22;08.12.2015;Y;12;15;25;33;23;45
A;PX67;09.12.2015;X;0;0,3;2;3;7;8;8,5;9,5
A;PX67;09.12.2015;Y;22;45;35;48;55;60;62;58"""

import csv
headers = None
data = []
reader = csv.reader(text.splitlines(), delimiter=';', quotechar='"')
for row in reader:
    if headers is None:
        headers = row
        continue
    std_columns = row[:len(headers) - 1]
    series = [float(x.replace(",", ".")) for x in row[len(headers):]]
    data.append([*std_columns, series])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers)
df = df.pivot(index=["Machine", "Process", "Date"], columns="Statistic", values="Data_Series")
df = df.explode(["X", "Y"]).reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks for this approach. As you noticed, one main issue for me was uploading the data. Once uploaded as a csv file, I believe I will be able to use/apply your code. It works fantastically if I have inline data, as you showed above. Thanks